# Fluorine Client only working when Charles Web proxy is open

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, netconnection, fluorinefx

I created a console application that it should run every hour in order to push updates to a different server using FluorineFx for C# client (NetConnection). It works great, but only when I have Charles open and so I can see what is being sent. On the other hand, if Charles is closed, it does not send the data.

Thx.

Comment: You'll need to share more information about what happens when Charles is not running.  How exactly is the connection being made?  Does it connect? Does it send data? Does the server show the connection?  Does the server receive data?  Does the server send a response?  Does the client receive any response?  If you can't answer all these questions, then add more logging.  You can also test with a more passive monitoring app like WireShark (I use Charles daily and love it, so not saying anything bad against Charles.. just in this particular case, obviously it's affecting your testing).

Comment: I now notice that this is happening intermittent. Sometimes is sending the data using AMF and sometimes does not work. I am now installing WireShark. Thx and I will let you know all my findings.

Comment: Did you find anything yet? I've had the same problem on my local machine using flex-weborb. Some of my colleagues have the same issue while others don't... very strange. Have even contacted weborb but they couldn't help me either... Maybe it's a security thing... crossdomain? Maybe using the ip-address instead of the name of the server?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but I recently encountered the same problem and found a solution. The issue is that Fluorine does not call the Close() method on the HttpWebResponse objects and as a result .NET keeps the object alive indefinitely, which causes subsequent requests to eventually block on the default connections-per-host limit.

I found two such cases in RemotingClient.cs, calling HttpWebResponse.Close() after you are done with the response fixed the problem for me.